# macos mongodb service running, but not connected to server, mongo console won't load

Tags: mongodb, service, terminal, homebrew

I have installed mongodb-community@4.2 using brew and the service shows as running. When I run:

```
brew services list
```

I get:

```
mongodb-community started <me> 
/Users/<me>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist.
```

If I look at local host 27017 it shows no connection. So when I run

```
mongo
```

to get the mongo console running, I get the following:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/? 
compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-02-04T12:30:20.881-0700 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to 
server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error 
connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-02-04T12:30:20.885-0700 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-02-04T12:30:20.885-0700 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Is anyone familiar with this issue? I would appreciate the help. Thanks.